# Filling a GridControl's Datasource with List(Of List(Of String))

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

(I modified the following code to simplify it for this question)
I would like to populate a DataGridcontrol with a list created at runtime:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim FieldsOfDocument As New List(Of String)
    Dim FoundDocuments As List(Of List(Of String))
    Dim nColumns = 3
    Dim nRows = 13
    FoundDocuments = New List(Of List(Of String))
    For i = 1 To nRows
        FieldsOfDocument = New List(Of String)
        For t = 1 To nColumns
            FieldsOfDocument.Add("Col " & t & " Row " & i)
        Next
        FoundDocuments.Add(FieldsOfDocument)
    Next
    GridControl1.DataSource = FoundDocuments
End Sub
```

nColumns and nRows belong to these simplyfied things - in the real code each row represents a custom class.

I expected to get a 13x3 Grid and in each cell a string with the given Column and Row.
When examining FoundDocuments in the last line of code it looks okay​ imho
[image: Looks okay]

But the grid will be populated with 2 columns, "Capacity" and "Count".
[image: Result]

What is my lack of information or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out: [GridControl does not support a two-dimensional array as a data source](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q514495/how-to-assign-an-array-to-a-gridcontrol)

Using a DataTable with my data did the job.